# Wrong cardinality on "over partition by" query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, window-functions

I have a table with code, send_date, and send_id as pk, on oracle 12.1.0.2

I need to fetch some values for the last code send of each value.

```sql
select  * from (
select code, some_column,
row_number() over (partition by code order by send_date desc, send_id desc) n
from my_table
) where n=1
```

Oracle made a cardinality estimation of 1 row due "where n=1" so choose a very bad execution plan on complex querys that use the previous SQL as subquery.

I assume that is a oracle bug
https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2118138_1.html

There is any workarround to bypass this bug?.

Comment: The page you linked to lets you see a sort of workaround, and possible patches, if you click through the 'sign-in' button?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be a bug.  More likely it is just a failure of the optimizer based on available statistics.

For your query and the queries below, I would recommend an index on `(code, send_date desc, send_id desc, some_column)`.

Here are two alternative methods of writing the query, so you can compare performance:

```
select code, 
       max(some_column) keep (dense rank first order by send_date desc, send_id desc) as somecolumn
from my_table
group by code;
```

And:

```
select t.code, t.some_column
from my_table t
where (t.send_date, t.send_id) = (select t2.send_date, t2.send_id
                                  from my_table t2
                                  where t2.code = t.code
                                 )
```